# Make function a Conditional Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a simple function on CodeIgniter 3 that fetches some data from the database using a simple query with a refine variable :

```
function  search($term){

    $this->db->like('sReference',$term)
         ->or_like('nReference', $term)
         ->or_like('sSearch', $term)
         ->or_like('sSort', $term);

    $query = $this->db->get('tReference');
    $ret['rows'] = $query->result();
    $ret['number'] = $query->num_rows();

return $ret;
}
```

Also I need the same query for another search method but just adding two lines like so :

```
function  search($term){
//Affichage de sproduits
$this->db->like('sReference',$term)
->or_like('nReference', $term)
->or_like('sSearch', $term)
->or_like('sSort', $term)
->join('tManufacturer','nManufacturer=tReference.nManufacturer')
->where('nStatus',$status);

$query = $this->db->get('tReference');
$ret['rows'] = $query->result();
$ret['number'] = $query->num_rows();

return $ret;
}
```

My Question is : **Is there any way to make a condition on it (knowing that I use a different search forms for both of the queries), or I must make two separate queries?**

And thanks to all of you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course. Add 2 parameters to the funtion, you can make it very flexible if you like.

```
function  search($term, $join=array(), $where=array()){
    //Affichage de sproduits
    $this->db->select('*')
             ->from('tReference');
             ->like('sReference',$term)
             ->or_like('nReference', $term)
             ->or_like('sSearch', $term)
             ->or_like('sSort', $term);
    if ( is_array($join) && count($join) == 2 ) {
        $this->db->join($join[0], $join[1]);
    }
    if ( is_array($where) && count($where) ==  2 ) {
        $this->db->where($where[0],$where[1]);
    }

    $query = $this->db->get();
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $ret['rows'][] = $row;
    }
    $ret['number'] = $query->num_rows();

    return $ret;
}
```

Now call it like this

```
$result = search('smith');   // just the ->like's
```

or if you want the join to be set

```
$result = search('smith', 
                 array('tManufacturer',
                       'nManufacturer=tReference.nManufacturer')
                );
```

or if you want the join and where set

```
$status = 'something';
$result = search('smith', 
                 array('tManufacturer',
                       'nManufacturer=tReference.nManufacturer'),
                 array('nStatus', $status)
                );
```

or if you just want the where clause and not the join

```
$status = 'something';
$result = search('smith', NULL, array('nStatus', $status) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much @RiggsFooly it's working, I do really appreciate it

Comment: See latest mod. I missed a bit where if your result returns more that one row you were not collecting all the results in the returned `$ret` array

Comment: @RiggsFooly Yes I've implemented in my code, I appreciate the idea from you, it's brilliant!